# Prove this Inequality using Induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Prove using induction that $|\prod_{j=1}^{n}a_{j} - 1| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{j}-1|$ for $|a_{j}| \leq 1$.

So far, I have the Base Case: When $n=1$, we have $|a_{1} - 1| = |a_{1} - 1|$.  The inductive step assumes that for some $k \geq 2$, $|\prod_{j=1}^{k}a_{j} - 1| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{k}|a_{j}-1|$.  Then I am trying to prove that this implies it is true for $k+1$, by doing something like this:

$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1} |a_{j} - 1| = |a_{k+1} - 1| + \sum_{j=1}^{k}|a_{j} - 1| \geq |a_{k+1} - 1| + |\prod_{j=1}^{k}a_{j} - 1|$...

And I am unsure about how to proceed from here. I think I should use the condition $|a_{j}| \leq 1$ at some point. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Is there some condition on the $a_j$? This seems false if they are large.

Comment: yes!  I forgot to add that, I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently we want to show $$|a_1...a_n-1|\leq n-(a_1+...+a_n)$$
Let's do the induction step: having inequality for $n$ let's prove for $n+1$. Let $\lambda =a_1 \cdot ... \cdot a_n$ then note $|\lambda a_{n+1}-1|=1-\lambda a_{n+1}$ so we need to show $$1-\lambda a_{n+1} \leq n+1 - (a_1+...+a_{n+1})$$

We have by induction step $1-\lambda \leq n-(a_1+...+a_n)$ hence
$$n+1 - (a_1+...+a_{n+1})\geq 1-\lambda+1-a_{n+1}\geq1-\lambda a_{n+1}$$
the last inequality holds since
$$1-\lambda+1-a_{n+1}-(1-\lambda a_{n+1})=1-\lambda-a_{n+1}(1-\lambda)=(1-\lambda)(1-a_{n+1})\geq 0$$

Comment: The RHS of the inequality would make more sense if $a_i$ are complex, and that means the first line of your answer (saying that those are equivalent) is not true.

Comment: I thought $a_j \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This inequality actually has a more general version which embraces your inequality as a special case:

> Let $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ and $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ be complex numbers of modulus at most $1$, then 
>   $$|z_1 \cdots z_n - w_1 \cdots w_n| \leq \sum_{j = 1}^n |z_j - w_j|.$$

To finish the induction step, decompose $z_1 \cdots z_n - w_1 \cdots w_n$ as follows:

$$ z_1 \cdots z_n - w_1 \cdots w_n = (z_1 - w_1)z_2\cdots z_n + w_1(z_2 \cdots z_n - w_2 \cdots w_n).$$